# Simple Hash Ring Implementation

Tags: java, hash-map

## Introduction

I have been reading about [Consistent Hashing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Consistent_hashing) and in an attempt to better understand the concept, I wanted to implement a simple hash ring.

I did not implement the concept of virtual nodes / replication across multiple node. The focus of this exercise was to build a simple implementation of an in-memory hash ring where nodes and key/value pairs could be added and removed.

## Discussion

The idea was that nodes and entries could occupy "positions" along the circumference of the hash ring. These positions would be represented by `int`s from `0` to `Integer.MAX_INTEGER`.

A client of the `SimpleHashRing` could add / remove nodes at certain "positions". They could also add / remove entries with a certain key - and there would be a mapping of each key to a position on the hash ring. These entries would then be assigned (based on their key's position) to the next node on the ring in ascending order, wrapping from `Integer.MAX_INTEGER` to `0`, if necessary.

### Design Decisions

#### The `HashRing` interface

Putting a `Position` class on the interface itself is restrictive in the sense that each implementation of the `HashRing` interface, must use a similar "position" paradigm. Maybe this is too restrictive?

#### The `SimpleHashRing` implementation

I throw an exception if a hash ring instance is created without at least one node. This seemed reasonable to me, since I couldn't think of a use-case where you'd want to use a hash ring without at least one node defined.

I basically have two internal data structures - a `List` of `Position`s that represent the `Position`s of the nodes in the hash ring, sorted from smallest `Position` to largest `Position`.

I also have a `Map` from `Position`s to a `Map` of key/value pairs that represent node positions to the entries located at that position.

These two data structures should support the behavior of adding and removing nodes in the hash ring.

## Implementation

### The `HashRing` interface

```java
public interface HashRing<Key, Value> {
    class AtLeastOneNodeMustExist extends Exception {
    }

    class Position implements Comparable<Position> {
        private final int value;

        public Position(int value) {
            if (0 > value) {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("value must be non-negative");
            }
            this.value = value;
        }

        public int getValue() {
            return value;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean equals(Object o) {
            if (this == o) return true;
            if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
            Position position = (Position) o;
            return value == position.value;
        }

        @Override
        public int hashCode() {
            return Objects.hash(value);
        }

        @Override
        public int compareTo(Position o) {
            return Integer.compare(this.value, o.value);
        }
    }

    void addNode(Position position);

    void removeNode(Position position) throws AtLeastOneNodeMustExist;

    Optional<Value> addEntry(Key key, Value value);

    Optional<Value> removeEntry(Key key);

    Optional<Value> getValue(Key key);
}
```

### The `SimpleHashRing` implementation

````java
public class SimpleHashRing<Key, Value> implements HashRing<Key, Value> {
    private final List<Position> nodePositions;
    private final Map<Position, Map<Key, Value>> entriesByPosition;
    private final Function<Key, Position> keyToPositionCalculator;

    public SimpleHashRing(final Set<Position> nodePositions, final Function<Key, Position> keyToPositionCalculator) throws AtLeastOneNodeMustExist {
        if (nodePositions.isEmpty()) {
            throw new AtLeastOneNodeMustExist();
        }

        this.nodePositions = nodePositions
                .stream()
                .sorted(Comparator.comparingInt(Position::getValue))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
        this.entriesByPosition = nodePositions
                .stream()
                .collect(
                        Collectors.toMap(
                                Function.identity(),
                                (v) -> new HashMap<>()
                        )
                );
        this.keyToPositionCalculator = keyToPositionCalculator;
    }

    @Override
    public void addNode(final Position position) {
        final Map<Key, Value> positionEntries = entriesByPosition.putIfAbsent(position, new HashMap<>());
        if (null == positionEntries) {
            final int followingNodePosition = Math.abs(Collections.binarySearch(nodePositions, position) + 1);
            final int currentNodeIndex = Math.max(followingNodePosition, 0);
            nodePositions.add(currentNodeIndex, position);

            final Map<Key, Value> followingNodeEntries = entriesByPosition.get(nodePositions.get(followingNodePosition));
            final Map<Key, Value> currentNodeEntries = followingNodeEntries
                    .entrySet()
                    .stream()
                    .filter(
                            e -> 0 > this.keyToPositionCalculator.apply(e.getKey()).compareTo(position)
                    )
                    .collect(
                            Collectors.toMap(
                                    Map.Entry::getKey,
                                    Map.Entry::getValue
                            )
                    );
            entriesByPosition.put(position, currentNodeEntries);
            followingNodeEntries.keySet().removeAll(currentNodeEntries.keySet());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void removeNode(final Position position) throws AtLeastOneNodeMustExist {
        final Map<Key, Value> entries = entriesByPosition.get(position);
        if (null != entries) {
            if (1 < entriesByPosition.size()) {
                final int currentNodeIndex = Collections.binarySearch(nodePositions, position);
                final int followingNodeIndex = (currentNodeIndex + 1) % nodePositions.size();
                this.entriesByPosition.get(this.nodePositions.get(followingNodeIndex)).putAll(entries);
                entriesByPosition.remove(position);
                nodePositions.remove(currentNodeIndex);
                return;
            }

            throw new AtLeastOneNodeMustExist();
        }
    }


    @Override
    public Optional<Value> addEntry(final Key key, final Value value) {
        return getEntriesForKey(key).map(entries -> entries.put(key, value));
    }

    @Override
    public Optional<Value> removeEntry(final Key key) {
        return getEntriesForKey(key).map(entries -> entries.remove(key));
    }

    @Override
    public Optional<Value> getValue(final Key key) {
        return getEntriesForKey(key).map(entries -> entries.get(key));
    }

    private Optional<Map<Key, Value>> getEntriesForKey(final Key key) {
        return Optional.ofNullable(
                entriesByPosition.get(
                        nodePositions.get(calculateNodePositionForKey(key))
                )
        );
    }

    private int calculateNodePositionForKey(final Key key) {
        final int nodePositionIndex;
        {
            final int searchedIndex = Collections.binarySearch(nodePositions, keyToPositionCalculator.apply(key));
            if (0 > searchedIndex) {
                nodePositionIndex = Math.abs(searchedIndex) - 1;
            } else {
                nodePositionIndex = searchedIndex;
            }
        }

        return nodePositionIndex % nodePositions.size();
    }
}
```
````

Comment: [`java.util.Map<K, V>`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Map.html#method-summary) is deplorably **fat**, still: why not keep its naming?

Answer (score 1):

### Usability

I tried looking at your code from the perspective of someone who wants to use it, and from that perspective it is rather clunky.

If I want a map, I can use it like so:

```
Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put("key", "value");
```

I can then access objects in the map via `map.get("key")`.

If I want to make use of a HashRing...

```
HashRing<String, Object> hashRing = new SimpleHashRing<>(
    Set.of(new Position(0)),
    s -> new Position(s.hashCode() % 255) //Pretend I wrote something that indices strings alphabetically based on their first four bytes
);
hashRing.addEntry("key", "value");
```

Okay, a bit more effort, but seems workable. `Position` rather than `int` is the most annoying thing here; the compiler doesn't stop me from putting negative numbers into a `Position` and so all it does is add syntactic sugar.

Now, if I wanted to play with the size of the hash ring, I can add and remove Positions... but I can't query which ones I currently have.

And if I wanted to iterate over the contents of the hash ring, I... can't. The only thing I can do is store and retrieve by key.

I can `removeNode` a Position that doesn't exist on the ring, I can `addNode` a Position that already exists on the ring (which both will silently do nothing).

Looking at your current implementation, I find it hard to come up with a use case where a hash ring would fit better than a hash map. Both support storing arbitrary key-value mappings. But the hash map doesn't require me to come up with my own bucketing algorithm (and if I needed it, I could override `hashCode`). The hash map also allows me to retrieve all entries.